# Need to change date list string to datetime [PYTHON]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I'm having some issue with converting a list (string) to DateTime format, the data come like this above:

```
df[arrive time] = 
28/11/2022 08:01
28/11/2022 08:01
28/11/2022 08:03
28/11/2022 08:15
28/11/2022 08:16
28/11/2022 08:17
28/11/2022 08:20
28/11/2022 08:20
28/11/2022 08:21
28/11/2022 08:22
28/11/2022 08:23
28/11/2022 08:30
28/11/2022 08:30
```

I try this way:

```
for i in range(len(df['Arrive time'])):
     datas = df['Arrive time'][i]
     datas = pd.to_datetime(datas, format ='%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
```

at the csv file come with seconds, but here, the DF didn't bring the complete data, I remove seconds but still bringing me errors.

the error:

> ValueError: time data '28/11/2022 08:01' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S' (match)

I tryed other methods but I didn't found one that works.
If someone know where are the answer for this problem, I'll be glad if notice me here.

Comment: Don't loop, use `df['arrive time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrive time'], dayfirst=True)` or `df['arrive time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrive time'], format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M')`

Comment: I get off loop and seconds... but still same error message

Comment: please provide a reproducible example, the first approach worked on your current example

Comment: I tryed the second approach, the first one solve it!
Thank you one more time @mozway